# Change of NLS_LANG

Tags: oracle, linux, sqlplus, encoding

Until not long ago, the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` and the `NLS_LANG` were both `ISO88591`. We deliver to production some scripts encoded in `ISO88591`.

Since they changed their `NLS_LANG` in `utf8`, they have a problem charging our `ISO88591` scripts which seem to be normal because special characters are not recognized.

They would like the `NLS_LANG` to be `utf8`, but is there a way to change it (what is the command line?) to `ISO8859` only when they are in charge of our scripts?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the OS. The `NLS_LANG` is just an environment variable that you need to set. This variable makes the SQL*Net to convert the character-set of the database into this character-set and reversed when sending it to the database.

In Linux you need to add the following line at the start of your script:

```
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.ISO8859
```

Perhaps you must change the `AMERICAN_AMERICA` into the value that you use.

Comment: yes it is linux...doing the export works in thesql plus session only ? some other people using sqlplus on the same server will have naturally NLS_LANG utf8?

Comment: This only works in the script.

Comment: it means you have to pu it in every script you send ?

Comment: Yes you must. Other solution is that you use a special user to run these scripts and put it in the `.bash_profile` of that user.

Comment: Correct character set name in for Oracle would be `WE8ISO8859P1`